# Move command from bat file opens another window

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, ms-dos

I have a .bat file that moves a file; however, it is also opening the file in a new window, which I don't want it to do. Is there a way to avoid opening a new window or at least an option to close the window after moving the file?

In the example below, the batch file opens another window on each move command and does not continue after I close the window manually.

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\source\*.txt') do (
move c:\source\%%f C:\destination\myfile.TXT
IF EXIST myfile.TXT start /wait dtexec /F ImportFile.dtsx
IF EXIST myfile.TXT start /wait ren myfile.TXT myfile%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.TXT 
move C:\destination\myfile_* C:\destination\OldFiles\
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `start /wait ren ...`:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\source\*.txt') do (
    move c:\source\%%f C:\destination\myfile.TXT
    IF EXIST myfile.TXT (
        start /wait dtexec /F ImportFile.dtsx
        ren myfile.TXT myfile%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.TXT
    )
    move C:\destination\myfile_* C:\destination\OldFiles\
)
```